# Can't boot after removing Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bootloader

I had a dual boot computer with Ubuntu and Windows. I followed [this](https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-in-a-windows-10-dual-boot-system/) guide with the 'What if you don't have a Windows Installation', i.e. I ran `bcdedit /set “{bootmgr}” path \efi\microsoft\boot\bootmgfw.efi`. I actually got 'command completed successfully' and I proceeded to remove my Ubuntu partition. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to boot to Windows.

I then created a bootable Windows USB and tried to follow the 'Remove the GRUB bootloader' section however I got 'Access Denied' when I ran `bootrec /fixboot`.

I then stumbled across [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-bootrec-fixboot-access-denied/7bd2f82b-b2f2-459a-95f5-5f4e6f717d2c) thread which linked to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-cant-boot/5b675a98-ac85-46f1-894a-9a8ac016caec) thread which said that you can fix it with the `bcdboot N:\windows /s M:` command (I had to use different letters for my disks but the concept holds).

I now manage to boot into Windows but it needs the USB to be inserted. I understand that it is using the bootloader off of the USB but now I can't switch that back...how can I fix it? I can't boot into the USB as a recovery device, it just defaults to the bootloader now. I can't get back to the command line to set the 'correct' bootloader now. When I try to go to 'Advanced Options' it only shows UEFI Options. If I try to boot without UEFI it defaults to the grub installation.

Any suggestions on how to proceed please?

Comment: Good job on your research, but there's several questions here on this site for similar or the same issue as well. This one looks promising: https://superuser.com/questions/935488/remove-one-of-multiple-operating-system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove one of multiple Operating System](https://superuser.com/questions/935488/remove-one-of-multiple-operating-system)

Comment: It does not because I don't have access to another bootable USB (my current one is my current boot drive) or Ubuntu.

Comment: USBs are cheap and easy to get, usually. Are you able to get another?

Comment: You need to do Startup Repair, which needs a boot USB.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I mentioned that, however as I said, it is immediately booting into windows using the USB as the bootloader. If I try to enter the Advanced Settings then it only allows me to change the UEFI settings (because I am set to UEFI). If I decide to go to Legacy boot, the BIOS does not detect the USB as a bootable USB so it ends up not working either. I need to break this loop somewhow.

Comment: @music2myear I tried your solution. Uninstall OS command only allows me to delete Windows which is not what I want. I already deleted the Ubuntu partition anyway so there is no need to further delete an OS. The Fix MBR did not work either.