# Unable to install Grub manually

Tags: linux, installation, grub, kali-linux, grub2

I sent as unable to install Grub

It says that cannot find efi directory

Please refer the image for error details

I am installing it from live Kali linux

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHQ2k.jpg]

Comment: --efi-directory should point to the mountpoint of a EFI System Partition, which should be FAT-formatted; `findmnt /boot/efi`

Comment: You don't have an EFI partition so why are you attempting to provide one?

Comment: Then how to install grub

Comment: and a copy of the text would be more useful than an awful screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't access GRUB, you'll need to repair it. Boot Repair Disk is a rescue disk that includes the Boot Repair tool.

- Runs Boot-Repair rescue tool automatically at start-up
- Also contains [OS-Uninstaller](https://superuser.com/questions/930725/how-to-delete-os-from-boot-menu/930741#930741) and Boot-Info tools
- Repairs recent (UEFI) computers as well as old PCs that have BIOS

#### How to get and use the disk

1. Download [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/?source=directory)
2. Make a Boot Repair live USB flash drive using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Rufus is a Windows utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash drives, such as USB flash drives, memory sticks, etc. (Do not burn it on a CD/DVD if your PC came with Windows 8 or Windows 10.)
3. Insert the Boot Repair disk, remove all other USB disks, and reboot the PC. Select the Boot Repair live USB flash drive as the device to boot from.
4. Choose your language.
5. Connect to the internet if possible.
6. Click *Recommended repair*.
7. Reboot the PC.

This solves the majority of boot sector/GRUB/MBR problems.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried boot-repair yet? If not, open your favorite search engine and look for boot-repair. Go to the help.ubuntu website. Then follow the instructions and install boot repair. Boot repair should open automatically if you installed it properly for the first time. If not, open up the terminal ( ctrl + T ) and write 'boot-repair' -without the ' - this will open boot repair. Once opened, wait boot repair to scan systems. Once it's done, click recommended repair and wait. You might want to share the logs, this will help a lot (boot repair is going to ask you after it's done) By the way, if you encounter any errors during opening boot repair, then you should try to open boot repair with an extra 'sudo'. The command should look like this 'sudo boot-repair' .

And do these on your real installation, never on your live cd. In my point of view, installing GRUB on real OS is better then installing on live cd. Feel free to comment below this post if you have any questions. Have a good day