# How to delete obsolete boot options from EFI?

Tags: partitioning, uefi, efi, boot-partition, refind

After installing and overwriting several operating systems, my EFI partition looks quite messy now:

[image]

Currently, there are only two operating systems on my machine: macOS, and FreeBSD, which means I no longer need the "Ubuntu" and "TrueOS" boot options.

How can I remove these obsolete boot options from the EFI partition?

Comment: See this   https://superuser.com/questions/930725/how-to-delete-os-from-boot-menu

Comment: The question and answer to which Biswa links refers to the EFI's built-in boot manager, which stores information on its boot loaders in NVRAM. This question, though, shows a rEFInd screen shot. rEFInd does not stores its boot options in NVRAM; it re-scans for boot loaders on every boot. Therefore, the solution will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rEFInd builds its boot menu "fresh" every time it runs. (An exception is if you use manual boot stanzas -- but if this were the case, you'd presumably be aware of this fact and know how to change them.) Thus, if you're seeing boot entries for OSes you've deleted, the cause is almost certainly that you haven't *completely* deleted the OSes in question. In most cases, the boot loader files reside on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) usually in a subdirectory of `EFI`; for instance, `EFI\ubuntu` for Ubuntu. rEFInd usually displays the complete filename, and the name or a description of the volume, under the icons when you highlight an option. For instance, in your screen shot, the description reads `Boot EFI\boot\bootx64-trueos.efi from EFI`. Thus, to remove that entry, you'd delete that file.

Of course, this means you must know how to access your ESP. The details of how to do this vary from one OS to another. Under macOS, you can use the `mountesp` script that comes with rEFInd. (Running the script will produce a message revealing where the ESP has been mounted.) I don't know offhand whether FreeBSD mounts the ESP by default, or where it's commonly mounted.

Note that deleting the boot loader is not always appropriate. For instance, if you want to *hide* an entry without making it completely inaccessible, you should use `dont_scan_files`, `dont_scan_dirs`, or `dont_scan_volumes` in `refind.conf` to hide the entry. You might do this if the rEFInd boot menu entry is for a tool that you want to leave installed on the ESP, but you just don't want to see a boot entry for it. (Maybe it's something you run from an EFI shell, or that's launched from a boot loader whose entry you want to keep.) Entries for BIOS-mode boot loaders may also need to be handled differently, such as by disabling BIOS-boot option scanning via the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf`. I don't think any of these cases apply to you, though; I mention this only for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I have a boot option named `Boot Fallback boot loader from EFI`, which actually boots to FreeBSD. I tried to edit `/Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind/refind.conf` to change its appearance (i.e. icon and label), but I don't know where the loader resides. Do you know where can I find the loader for `Boot Fallback boot loader from EFI`?

Comment: The fallback boot loader is `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` (or equivalent for other CPU types).