# Remove grub after completely wiping the Ubuntu HDD

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I had Windows 10 on my laptop and I needed to install Ubuntu. I followed the instructions and installed Ubuntu on a separate HDD using the "install Ubuntu alongside the existing Windows 10". Windows 10 is on a separate SSD.
After rebooting the grub menu never appeared and Windows 10 loaded as usually, so I had to enter the bios boot menu on booting my laptop by holding F11 and manually choose the Ubuntu hdd as a booting device.

Then I decided to get rid of the Ubuntu since I wasn't able to solve the problem of hanging on shutdown. I deleted all the partitions from HDD, completely re-mapped the partitions and installed Mint.

And now I cannot boot Mint: there is no grub again, but on pressing F11 I'm still seeing that the HDD is called Ubuntu. After trying to load it I enter grub command line and that's basically it...

What went wrong and how to be able to boot the new Mint installation, and what was the correct way to wipe the Ubuntu HDD?

I guess this is not the MBR record thing. The menu I'm talking about is the menu of available devices, it also includes USB drives if any of them are connected and Network cards.

I'm completely satisfied with the F11 way since it doesn't affect MBR and Windows at all, so I would prefer this to having fully functional grub.

Thanks.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this could at least leave an explanation. Not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have 2 issues - the question you asked - about removing grub - I believe @Keltari deleted answer is correct here.

The issue you have described, however, is not with grub but actually the UEFI.  This can be done with programs like uefibootmgr in Linux or easyuefi in Windows.

The answer to your question is thus the same as [How to delete OS from boot menu](https://superuser.com/questions/930725/how-to-delete-os-from-boot-menu#931016) (but I don't think the question is a dup)

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for, thank you. I had no idea what UEFI was since it's my first laptop for last 7 years. I even didn't have the vocabulary to correctly google it... Not sure why they downvoted me.