# How to delete extra OS entries from bios

Tags: bios, uefi, dualboot

I had an dual boot installation with windows and ubuntu. Recently, my ubuntu installation grub failed. I tried repairing it which brought a new entry into my boot selection screen. Eventually I deleted ubuntu and installed a new version of Ubuntu which added a yet another entry into the list as shown below.

[image: IMG:]

I would like to delete both ubuntu(P2: ST1000DM003-1SB102) from the list as they belonged to the deleted ubuntu installation (boots into windows).

How do I do that since my bios settings can only disable an entry.

Answer (score 7):

The firmware usually has the option to delete entries as well, it just might not be very obvious (i.e. probably done through a separate section in Advanced, *not* through the usual "Boot order").

If you can boot into Linux in UEFI mode, use `efibootmgr`:

- `efibootmgr` to list entries (or `efibootmgr -v` in older versions);
- `efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` to delete an entry by number.

If you can boot into Windows in UEFI mode, use `bcdedit`:

- `bcdedit /enum firmware` to list entries;
- `bcdedit /delete "{GUID}"` to delete an entry by its "identifier".

Comment: If you're using PowerShell, you need to add `--%` so it doesn't parse it as a script-block. `bcdedit --% /delete {GUID}`

Answer (score 2):

Open Command Prompt in administrator, then in that type 'bcdedit /enum firmware' this will list a load of entries, find the one that corresponds to your Ubuntu installation and copy the identifier, be careful to copy the correct identifier. Then type 'bcdedit delete {identifier}' where {identifier} is replaced by the identifier of the entry you are trying to remove.

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify the entries that grub gets. Launch linux, then navigate to `/etc/grub.d`
in that directory there should be a file that lists those entries you do not want. Either remove them, or if you are not comfortable of removing just making them non-executable. If the file for the entry is not there, then it is in one of the files and being picked up as an OS. Here is a link to help you out.

https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/grub2-revisited/

Comment: The EFI boot menu is completely separate from the GRUB menu.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, they specified grub failed and attempted to repair it thus resulting another entry. So I was not sure which was needed. Your answer is valid if EFI boot menu is needed instead of grub boot menu.